# Python: get secure cookies using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Let me explain what is the issue in my case:

1. Go to site: "https://example.com"
2. Choose login using Google account;
3. You will be redirected to google login page;
4. Fill username and password and click on "Next";
5. Login with success;
6. Open Developers Tools and > Application, in Cookies it will be possible to find some secure cookies like: "access_token" and "USERAUTH"
7. When I'm trying to retrieve this values using Selenium - with no luck. However, in browser I'm able to see required values in Developer Tools.

So, How is it possible to retrieve all cookies from the site?

Below example of my code:

```
def main():
    main_window_handle = None
    session = requests.Session()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.delete_all_cookies() # clean up the prior login sessions
    driver.get('https://example.com/') # change the url to your website
    while not main_window_handle:
        main_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sign-in-container__social-services\"]/button").click()
    signin_window_handle = None
    while not signin_window_handle:
        for handle in driver.window_handles:
            if handle != main_window_handle:
                signin_window_handle = handle
                break
    driver.switch_to.window(signin_window_handle)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]/span/span").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"passwordNext\"]/span/span").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(10)
    cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
    print(driver.get_cookies())
    response = session.get('https://example.com/')
    print(session.cookies.get_dict())
    cookies_dict = {}
    for cookie in cookies_list:
        cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
    access_token = cookies_dict.get('access_token') # getting None on this step
    print(access_token)
    time.sleep(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```